# Issue with setting default value for a column (sql server 2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

The following syntax won't work:

```
ALTER TABLE MyCustomers 
ALTER COLUMN CompanyName SET DEFAULT 'A. Datum Corporation'
```

per url, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123.aspx

Error message:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'.

What gives?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to check the correct documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(v=sql.105).aspx. You linked to the Compact edition of SQL Server, but you're probably using the normal one...

Answer (score 1):

Per this question:
[How to set a default value for an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791675/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-an-existing-column)

The following will work on SQL Server, and has the added benefit of naming the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE MyCustomers 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeName DEFAULT 'A. Datum Corporation' FOR CompanyName;
```

Comment: Sorry - but the second statement is **not** valid T-SQL code - you **cannot** define a default constraint using a `SET DEFAULT` clause....

Comment: You are correct, I was looking at the document given in the question, which seems to be incorrect.  I fixed my answer.  Thank you.