# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET' IN ALTER STATEMENT

Tags: sql-server

I HAVE FOLLOWING QUERY... THROUGH WHICH I WANT TO ALTER DEFAULT VALUE

```
ALTER TABLE MBR_MST2 ALTER COLUMN MBR_STS SET DEFAULT 1
```

don't know why it is showing an error 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

Comment: @BobJarvis The question is for SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: you can refer my answer posted at below

Comment: @BlaZuRE - yep - forgot to switch the database type.  Haven't had my coffee yet...  :-)

Answer (score 3):

The query as follows will sort it out. Refer the below handy code sample has been written by Pinal Dave

```
ALTER TABLE MBR_MST2 
   ADD CONSTRAINT MBR_MST2_CONST DEFAULT 1 FOR MBR_STS
```

[Handy Script Link for Default Constraint](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/31/sql-server-create-default-constraint-over-table-column/)

Comment: You beat me by 47 seconds... Since i am new, should i delete my post?

Comment: you can keep it.. No prob

Comment: @jyparask In this situation I would normally upvote the first correct answer and delete mine except if I could think of some additional relevant information to add to it. But entirely up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Use ADD CONSTRAINT

```
ALTER TABLE MBR_MST2 ADD CONSTRAINT DF_NewSTS DEFAULT 1 FOR MBR_STS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) for your statement.  Your error is correct, the syntax is incorrect.

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791675/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-an-existing-column) for the correct syntax.

```
ALTER TABLE MBR_MST2 ADD CONSTRAINT Your_Constraint_Name DEFAULT 1 FOR MBR_STS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE MBR_MST2 ALTER COLUMN MBR_STS SET DEFAULT 1
```

Rewrite as

```
ALTER TABLE MBR_MST2 
add  constraint  DF_MBR_MST2_MBR_STS
Default 'DEFAULT 1' For MBR_STS
```

Open your table and refresh it's constraints folder and this constraint should be there.