# Alter column default value

Tags: sql, sql-server, default-value, notnull

I know you can change the default value of an existing column like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791675/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-an-existing-column):

```
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeName DEFAULT N'SANDNES' FOR CityBorn;
```

But according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187742%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) my query supposed to work:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL 
      CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT GetDate()
```

So here I'm trying to make my column Not Null and also set the Default value. But getting Incoorect Syntax Error near CONSTRAINT. Am I missing sth?

Comment: I think you need `ADD CONSTRAINT`, like in your first example.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think issue here is with the confusion between `Create Table` and `Alter Table` commands.
If we look at `Create table` then we can add a default value and default constraint at same time as:

```
<column_definition> ::= 
column_name <data_type>
    [ FILESTREAM ]
    [ COLLATE collation_name ] 
    [ SPARSE ]
    [ NULL | NOT NULL ]
    [ 
        [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ] DEFAULT constant_expression ] 
      | [ IDENTITY [ ( seed,increment ) ] [ NOT FOR REPLICATION ] 
    ]
    [ ROWGUIDCOL ]
    [ <column_constraint> [ ...n ] ] 
    [ <column_index> ]
 ex: 
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee 
(
     CreateDate datetime NOT NULL 
     CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT (getdate())
) 
ON PRIMARY;
```

you can check for complete definition here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174979.aspx

but if we look at the `Alter Table` definition then with `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN` you cannot add 
`CONSTRAINT` the options available for `ADD` are:

```
 | ADD 
    { 
        <column_definition>
      | <computed_column_definition>
      | <table_constraint> 
      | <column_set_definition> 
    } [ ,...n ]
```

Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms190273.aspx

So you will have to write two different statements one for Altering column as:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL;
```

and another for altering table and add a default constraint

`ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT GetDate() FOR CreateDate;`

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: right on spot. if i understand it correctly microsoft needs to update their content: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187742%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: no ..if you read the first line correctly then it `Specifies the properties of a column that is **added** to a table by using ALTER TABLE. So you can always write something as: `ALTER TABLE **ADD** COLUMN .. CONSTRAINT  .. DEFAULT ; `

Comment: wow you r right again :) microsoft needs to put those stars around "added" haha

Comment: Glad to see it helped you..:)

Answer (score 11):

There is no direct way to change default value of a column in SQL server, but the following parameterized script will do the work:

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @column NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @newDefault NVARCHAR(100);
SET @table = N'TableName';
SET @column = N'ColumnName';
SET @newDefault = N'0';

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT   name
    FROM     sys.default_constraints
    WHERE    parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table)
    AND      parent_column_id = COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(@table), @column, 'ColumnId')
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @constraintName AS NVARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE @constraintQuery AS NVARCHAR(2000);

    SELECT  @constraintName = name
    FROM    sys.default_constraints
    WHERE   parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table)
    AND parent_column_id = COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(@table), @column, 'ColumnId');

    SET @constraintQuery = N'ALTER TABLE ' + @table + N' DROP CONSTRAINT '
        + @constraintName + N'; ALTER TABLE ' + @table + N' ADD CONSTRAINT '
        + @constraintName + N' DEFAULT ' + @newDefault + N' FOR ' + @column;

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @constraintQuery;
END;
```

Just fill the parameters and execute. The script removes existing constraint and creates a new one with designated default value.

Comment: This is the best answer for all the questions related to 'how do I change a column's default value'? It takes into account that there is an existing default, and that default may have a system generated name, and it can be scripted and does not rely on manual observation/manipulation.

Answer (score 7):

It should be -

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ALTER COLUMN CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE MyTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT GetDate() FOR CreateDate;
```

Answer (score 6):

For altering an existing column you need to:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT GetDate() FOR CreateDate;
```

Comment: Is it recommended to execute these in reverse order, given that you may already have null values in `CreateDate`? I.e. you want to remove the null values by applying the default constraint, then make the column non-nullable.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN [**ALTER TABLE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(v=sql.110).aspx) examples:

**D. Adding a DEFAULT constraint to an existing column**

> *The following example creates a table with two columns and inserts a value into the first column, and the other column remains **NULL**. A **DEFAULT** constraint is then added to the second column. To verify that the default is applied, another value is inserted into the first column, and the table is queried.*

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.doc_exz ( column_a INT, column_b INT) ;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.doc_exz (column_a)VALUES ( 7 ) ;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.doc_exz
ADD CONSTRAINT col_b_def
DEFAULT 50 FOR column_b ;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.doc_exz (column_a) VALUES ( 10 ) ;
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.doc_exz ;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.doc_exz ;
GO
```

So in short, you need the `ADD CONSTRAINT`

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
    ALTER COLUMN CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL ;

ALTER TABLE MyTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT GetDate() FOR CreateDate;
```