# Use default for existing columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, default

I am new to SQL Server. It may be the very basic question.

I want to set a default value for a column having null values and which is already defined in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Not clear. You can put a default on a column, and if the column isn't specified in the insert it will be used. If you specify it but use null as a value, then null it will be, but if you are putting a null in there anyway, you could put a default in...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I think he is trying to create a default value for a column in an existing table. Is this correct @Sony?

Comment: If the column already exists, adding a default constraint to it will **not** touch the existing values (even if they are `NULL`). If you *add* a new column - then yes, you can set a default value and have it applied to all rows. For an existing column, you need to set the default constraint and then separately, in a second step, update the existing values

Comment: I have the column which is currently having null values... I want to put default values instead of null

Comment: @Aidan, good guess apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791675/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-an-existing-column).

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName DEFAULT N'DefaultValue' FOR ColumnName;
```