# I need to know how to make default to NULL for a column in mssql

Tags: database

I have a table abc in mssql which has column xyz which has its default  has been set to not null, so the insert query fails when it has null value, I need help to change the default so that it accepts null values, table has only one constraint and its not on the column that I want to modify .

Comment: `not null` is not a constraint. it's part of the table definition. `alter` the table.

Comment: I mentioned about the constraint because that's the post I saw on here,but anyways,,can you help me with the query ?

Comment: this is what I tried :   ALTER TABLE list ALTER COLUMN MED DEFAULT(NULL);

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE xyz
ALTER COLUMN xyz NVARCHAR(10) NULL
```

Alter should work fine here, obviously change NVARCHAR(10) to whatever type you need

Comment: Hey Ross,that fixed my issue, Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

According to ([How to set a default value for an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791675/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-an-existing-column))

You have 2 options:
1. Setting a constraint: 
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeName DEFAULT N'SANDNES' FOR CityBorn;

2. Add Default:
   ALTER TABLE Employee ADD DEFAULT 'SANDNES' FOR CityBorn