# Generate script for Default Value or Binding in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-scripts

Recently I set value for **`Default Value or Binding`** to **`(newid())`** in table design.

Now I want to generate scripts for the changes to execute on another database.

Can anyone please help me to **write/generate** script for these changes.

*Thanks in advance!*

**Note:** I have checked **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791675/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-an-existing-column)** solution but not helped me coz I want to generate script for all the tables in which I have made changes recently for **`Default Value or Binding`**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a default value for an existing column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791675/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-an-existing-column)

Answer (score 3):

Use the below query to generate the script for default constraints with default value `newid()`

```
SELECT 'alter table ' + Quotename(o.name)
       + ' add constraint ' + Quotename(dc.name)
       + ' default ' + dc.definition + ' for '
       + Quotename(c.name)
FROM   sys.default_constraints dc
       INNER JOIN sys.columns c
               ON dc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
                  AND dc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
       INNER JOIN sys.objects o
               ON o.object_id = dc.parent_object_id
WHERE  definition = '(newid())'
```

copy paste the result in new database and execute it create the default constraints.