# Default value for column Visual Studio Management Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, default-value

Hee Guys,

I have not worked with this database tool but is it possible to set a default value for a column?

I want the default value to be 1 how can I achieve this. It think you have to change something in the properties.

Can you tell me how?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a default value for an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791675/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-an-existing-column)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in two ways, by Management Studio GUI and by using t-sql. It described in following article, please check it out: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187872(v=sql.110).aspx