# Insert date while importing a flat file into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, flat-file, import-from-csv

I'm trying to import a flat file into SQL Server table using SSIS package. This package is scheduled to run everyday. I've already created an extra column before importing the file.

Ex:

Flat file on 01/08/2019:

```
001,Tony Stark,Ironman
014,Steve Rodgers, Captain America
```

Flat file on 01/09/2019:

```
414,Peter Parker, Spiderman
007,Clark Kent, Superman
```

**Expected result:**

After importing, table should look like this on 01/08/2019

```````
ID      Name              Alias                 Date
````    ``````            ``````                `````
001     Tony Stark        Ironman               2019-01-08  
014     Steve Rodgers     Captain America       2019-01-08
```````

like this on 01/09/2019

```````
ID      Name              Alias                 Date
````    ``````            ``````                `````
001     Tony Stark        Ironman               2019-01-08  
014     Steve Rodgers     Captain America       2019-01-08 
414     Peter Parker      Spiderman             2019-01-09
007     Clark Kent        Superman              2019-01-09
```````

Comment: You explained very well the sources and expected results but... what have you obtained instead?

Comment: @intruder What is the question?

Comment: @intruder from your profile it looks like you are asking a lot of question without replying on answers or accepting them!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in many ways:

**1- Add Derived Column to the package**

You can add a Derived Column Transformation in you Data Flow Task, and Use the `[System::StartTime]` variable which contains the time that the package started to run. Or you can use the `GETDATE()` function that returns the current date.

**2- Add a default value to your added Column**

You can add `GETDATE()` function as a default value to the column, so foreach new line inserted, the value of the current date will be assigned.

```
ALTER TABLE DestTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeName DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR [Date];
```

**References**

- [SSIS System Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables?view=sql-server-2017)
- [GETDATE (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/getdate-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)
- [How to set a default value for an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791675/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-an-existing-column)

Comment: Thanks! I'm using DEFAULT GETDATE() while creating the table. So every time a record is inserted, it writes the current date to that column.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to load the csv file into mysql, [load it into a new mysql table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

Then, use a [table alter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) to create a new date column. [Update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) that new table, setting the column to the desired date.

Then, insert the values from the new table into the final destination table, using mysql [insert-select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) syntax.

Finally, drop the new/temporary table.