# how to drop unnamed primary key constraint

Tags: sql, oracle10g

i created a table in oracle 10g as following :

```
CREATE TABLE studentTbl(
 studId VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY,
 StudName VARCHAR2(40)
 );
```

And now want to remove primary key from studId without dropping this column.
I searched about it and found
 [Dropping unnamed constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670946/dropping-unnamed-constraints)
 but it also could n't help me. Couldn't get sys.columns table or view.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
alter table studenttbl drop primary key;
```

More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#i2103997

<sup>(What is this `tbl` suffix for? Sounds like a terrible naming convention)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The question you link to isn't for Oracle. The system view [USER_CONSTRAINTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5249.htm#REFRN26047) has a list of all constraints. The P in the CONSTRAINT_TYPE column indicates that it's a primary key; you can utilise this to find other constraints.

You can use this view to generate the DDL necessary to drop the constraint (or to view other information).

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE studentTbl(
 studId VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY,
 StudName VARCHAR2(40)
 );

Table created.


select 'alter table ' || table_name
       || ' drop constraint ' || constraint_name || ';'
  from user_constraints
 where table_name = 'STUDENTTBL'
   and constraint_type = 'P';

'ALTERTABLE'||TABLE_NAME||'DROPCONSTRAINT'||CONSTRAINT_NAME||';'
----------------------------------------------------------------------

alter table STUDENTTBL drop constraint SYS_C0017725;
```

Comment: yeah, you are right. but my point ws that same logical thing i tried to find this constraints name. bt couldn't fetch it. Thanks for your help. Can't not vote.